# vlookup result NA, want to turn into a text box that updates info on corresponding vlookup database

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g81g2.png)OK, so what I am trying to figure out is how I can make the vlookup result box, (if na), become a text box that updates the corresponding vlookup col_index_number.

to explain better, I have another sheet that is listed with serial numbers and all the purchase information (dates, item number,etc.). So when I enter my serial number it pulls all the data. Now what I would like to do is, that when the serial number has no information (new/unassigned) and the vlookup results are NA, i would like to simply add the information in the same "NA" boxes, so that it updates the serial number page.

image 1 shows my first sheet. and the second is the data base on screen two.
I am currently using =VLOOKUP(C6,'Serial Numbers'!A5:F93,3,FALSE)

And I wanted to be able to enter the info on sheet one after the vlookup runs. all in the same boxes, so that I can actively update all the info from sheet one

[Sheet one, vlookup results from serial number input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g81g2.png)

Comment: You have not explained your problem clearly at all. Maybe you're saying you want to enter a new row of the array used by VLOOKUP() when the returned results are #N/A?  That means you would need dates, item numbers etc. for the new serial number.  Where is that information going to come from?

Comment: Please post a screen shot showing a mockup of what you'd like your worksheet to look like. You're going to have to use VBA to accomplish this.

Comment: added pictures. I don t know how to explain it better

Comment: Your edit mentions two images, but there is only one in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot accomplish this on a excel sheet. You need to use VBA. 
Set up a form with the fields you want. I would put 3 buttons on the bottom. One Lookup which would populate the fields with the lookup info, one update to update the excel sheet. And one to close the form.